# Remove a revision from SVN history

Tags: svn

I committed some sensitive data into the SVN by mistake. I don't want my collaborators to see these data. Can I revert the SVN to the previous state and remove the latest revision from SVN history (pretends that the latest commit were never made at all)?

Comment: If it's a password, even if you do manage to remove it, you should change the password wherever it's used. Assume it's been seen.

Comment: Above comment very true. How do you know no one has already checked out that revision? You can't change those.

Comment: If you're using Apache as your SVN server, then you should be able to check the server logs to actually see if the password-containing file has been checked out, cat'ed or exported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not easily - you can use svndump and svndumpfilter to filter out that revision, or if you have backups of the server side, restore from a backup before the checkin. In the first case you'll end up creating a new repository (new UUID) so everyone will know it's been changed server side. Sorry, but SVN is deliberately hard to actually remove data from.

Comment: Full directions are described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566327/delete-all-traces-of-a-svn-commit).